# How to store and retrieve HTML page with images in Android?

Tags: android, html, webview

When using JavaScript and HttpClient I'm getting HTML page in string and show this string in `webview.loadDataWithBaseURL`.

HTML page content showing fine but I'm not able to show image in webview.

Comment: Post your code for webview.loadDataWithBaseURL()

Comment: use base64 for images.

Comment: This was far too short for a Stack Overflow question, even in 2013. Voting to close, as it is appears to be abandoned.